# Using shaders from Shadertoy in Interface Builder (Xcode)

Tags: ios, opengl, opengl-es, interface-builder, pixel-shader

I'm attempting to see what shaders look like in Interface Builder using sprite kit, and would like to use some of the shaders at [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/howto).  To do it, I created a "shader.fsh" file, a scene file, and added a color sprite to the scene, giving it a custom shader (shader.fsh)

While very basic shaders seem to work:

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

Any attempt I make to convert shaders from [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/howto) cause Xcode to freeze up (spinning color ball) as soon as the attempt is made to render them.

The shader I am working with for example, is [this one](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lsfGWH):

```
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

float rand(vec2 co)
{
    return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    float size = 30.0;
    float prob = 0.95;

    vec2 pos = floor(1.0 / size * fragCoord.xy);

    float color = 0.0;
    float starValue = rand(pos);

    if (starValue > prob)
    {
        vec2 center = size * pos + vec2(size, size) * 0.5;

        float t = 0.9 + 0.2 * sin(iGlobalTime + (starValue - prob) / (1.0 - prob) * 45.0);

        color = 1.0 - distance(fragCoord.xy, center) / (0.5 * size);
        color = color * t / (abs(fragCoord.y - center.y)) * t / (abs(fragCoord.x - center.x));
    }
    else if (rand(fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy) > 0.996)
    {
        float r = rand(fragCoord.xy);
        color = r * (0.25 * sin(iGlobalTime * (r * 5.0) + 720.0 * r) + 0.75);
    }

    fragColor = vec4(vec3(color), 1.0);
}
```

I've tried:

- Replacing mainImage() with main(void) (so that it will be called)
- Replacing the iXxxxx variables (iGlobalTime, iResolution) and fragCoord variables with their related variables (based on the suggestions [here](http://battleofbrothers.com/sirryan/understanding-shaders-in-spritekit))
- Replacing some of the variables (iGlobalTime)...

While changing mainImage to main() and swapping out the variables got it to work without error in [TinyShading](http://tiny-shading.com) realtime tester app - the outcome is always the same in Xcode (spinning ball, freeze).  Any advice here would be helpful as there is a surprisingly small amount of information currently available on the topic.

Comment: Any news on this issue ?

Comment: @salocinx - I'd given up on it.  Are you having the same issues?

Comment: Not exactly the same issues... I tried to compile this one: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MtB3zW as you suggested and I also read the linked pages. I also replaced every unknown field with corresponding counterparts and also changed main's signature accordingly. But I receive some "non-const reference cannot bind to vector element" errors. X-Code did not hang so far with simple shaders, but the shader matrix functions seem to be implemented differently than those of the WebGL shader language... Apple did it different than the rest of the world - once more ... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get this working in SpriteKit using [SKShader](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skshader). I've been able to render every shader from ShaderToy that I've attempted so far. The only exception is that you must remove any code using `iMouse`, since there is no mouse in iOS. I did the following...

**1)** Change the `mainImage` function declaration in the ShaderToy to...

```
void main(void) {
    ...
}
```

The ShaderToy `mainImage` function has an input named `fragCoord`. In iOS, this is globally available as `gl_FragCoord`, so your `main` function no longer needs any inputs.

**2)** Do a replace all to change the following from their ShaderToy names to their iOS names...

- `fragCoord` becomes `gl_FragCoord`
- `fragColor` becomes `gl_FragColor`
- `iGlobalTime` becomes `u_time`

*Note: There are more that I haven't encountered yet. I'll update as I do*

**3)** Providing `iResolution` is slightly more involved...

`iResolution` is the viewport size (in pixels), which translates to the sprite size in SpriteKit. This used to be available as `u_sprite_size` in iOS, but has been removed. Luckily, Apple provides a nice example of how to inject it into your shader using [uniforms](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skuniform) in their [SKShader documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skshader).

**However**, as stated in `Shader Inputs` section of ShaderToy, the type of `iResolution` is `vec3` (x, y and z) as opposed to `u_sprite_size`, which is `vec2` (x and y). I am yet to see a single ShaderToy that uses the `z` value of `iResolution`. So, we can simply use a `z` value of zero. I modified the example in the Apple documentation to provide my shader an `iResolution` of type `vec3` like so...

```
let uniformBasedShader = SKShader(fileNamed: "YourShader.fsh")

let sprite = SKSpriteNode()
sprite.shader = uniformBasedShader       

let spriteSize = vector_float3(
    Float(sprite.frame.size.width),  // x                 
    Float(sprite.frame.size.height), // y
    Float(0.0)                       // z - never used
)

uniformBasedShader.uniforms = [    
    SKUniform(name: "iResolution", vectorFloat3: spriteSize)
]
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the change to the shader that works when loaded as a shader with swift:

```
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

float rand(vec2 co);

float rand(vec2 co)
{
    return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}

void main()
{
    float size = 50.0; //Item 1:
    float prob = 0.95; //Item 2:

    vec2 pos = floor(1.0 / size * gl_FragCoord.xy);

    float color = 0.0;
    float starValue = rand(pos);

    if (starValue > prob)
   {
        vec2 center = size * pos + vec2(size, size) * 0.5;

        float t = 0.9 + 0.2 * sin(u_time + (starValue - prob) / (1.0 - prob) * 45.0); //Item 3:

        color = 1.0 - distance(gl_FragCoord.xy, center) / (0.9 * size);
        color = color * t / (abs(gl_FragCoord.y - center.y)) * t / (abs(gl_FragCoord.x - center.x));
    }
    else if (rand(v_tex_coord) > 0.996)
    {
        float r = rand(gl_FragCoord.xy);
        color = r * (0.25 * sin(u_time * (r * 5.0) + 720.0 * r) + 0.75);
    }

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(color), 1.0);
}
```

Play with Item 1: to increase the number of stars in the sky the smaller the number the more stars I like the number to be around 50 not too dense
Item 2: changes the randomness or how close together the stars will appear 1 = none, 0.1 = side by side around 0.75 gives a nice feel.

Item 3 is where most of the magic happens this is the size and pulse of the stars.

```
float t = 0.9
```

Changing 0.9, will increase the initial star sign up or down a nice value is 1.4 not too big not too small.

```
float t = 0.9 + 0.2
```

Changing the second value in this equation 0.2, will increase the pulse effect width of the stars proportionally to the original size I like with 1.4 a value of 1.2.

To add the shader to your swift project add a sprite to the scene the size of the screen then add the shader like this:

```
let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode()
backgroundImage.texture = textureAtlas.textureNamed("any )
    backgroundImage.size = screenSize


        let shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "nightSky.fsh")
        backgroundImage.shader = shader
```